# Unable to run Airflow 1.10 on Mac OS

Tags: python, macos, airflow

The latest version of Airflow 1.10 requires some setup for the logger.

I carefully followed the [instructions](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/UPDATING.md#logging-update) and created a `config` folder with `airflow/config_templates/airflow_local_settings.py` and added it to `PYTHONPATH`.

Unfortunately when running airflow I get this error:

```
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'processor':
  Cannot resolve 'airflow.utils.log.file_processor_handler.FileProcessorHandler': 
    dlopen(/Users/arikliber/miniconda3/envs/py36-6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psutil/_psutil_osx.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2):
      Symbol not found: ___CFConstantStringClassReference
  Referenced from: /Users/arikliber/miniconda3/envs/py36-6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psutil/_psutil_osx.cpython-36m-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
    in /Users/arikliber/miniconda3/envs/py36-6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psutil/_psutil_osx.cpython-36m-darwin.so
```

Everything was installed on a fresh miniconda environment.

Anyone got Airflow 1.10 on a Mac OS (I have 10.13.6) and mind sharing the workflow?

Comment: It's rather an issue with `psutil`, not with `airflow`. When you run `python -c "import psutil"`, what do you get? If you have multiple Python versions installed, select the same that fails `airflow`, e.g. `python3.6 -c ` etc.

Comment: Oh it actually gives me an error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "....psutil/__init__.py", line 134, in <module>
    from . import _psosx as _psplatform
  File "..../psutil/_psosx.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import _psutil_osx as cext
ImportError: dlopen(/.....psutil/_psutil_osx.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: ___CFConstantStringClassReference
  Referenced from: ....psutil/_psutil_osx.cpython-36m-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in...psutil/_psutil_osx.cpython-36m-darwin.so`

Comment: Update: apparently Airflow somehow downgrades the version of `psutil` during installation. To fix that I just ran `pip install psutil --upgrade` AFTER installing airflow. Thanks, @hoefling for putting me on the right path!

Answer (score 1):

I used the brew installation of python 3.6, a venv from `-m venv` and installed airflow v 1.10 by checking out the source at branch v1-10-stable and installing with `pip -e <path/to/apache-airflow-src-dir>/` After installing I used `pip check` to find that click 7.0 had been installed by flask but that flask-appbuilder didn't like that, so I had to unstall that and install click 6.7. You could try and modify the `setup.py` to put flask-appbuilder before flask in the ordered requirements.